# Can you make an editable JavaFX ListView that contains complex objects?

Tags: java, javafx

I know how to make an editable ListView and how to make a ListView that holds complex objects but I can't seem to combine them.

Comment: The answer is yes. Have you learned about custom editable cells yet?

Comment: I haven't. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a custom cell factory so the application knows how to handle your custom objects. Aside from that, it should work very simliar to a normal editable `ListView`:

```
public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    class MyObj {

        String toDisplay;
        double rand;

        public MyObj(String toDisplay) {
            this.toDisplay = toDisplay;
            rand = Math.random();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ListView listView = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new MyObj("Item1"), new MyObj("Item2")));
        listView.setEditable(true);

        listView.setCellFactory((list) -> {
            return new TextFieldListCell(new StringConverter<MyObj>() {
                @Override
                public String toString(MyObj object) {
                    return object.toDisplay;
                }

                @Override
                public MyObj fromString(String string) {
                    return new MyObj(string);
                }
            });
        });

        HBox hbox = new HBox(listView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm .. really need the commit handler? Would expect the default handler to set the item (provided the TextFieldListCell has a converter, as yours does)

Comment: @kleopatra No, you're entirely correct - my bad. (I originally intended to write something extra in there to demo post edit commit hooks, but then decided that'd be needlessly complex then forgot to delete it...)